# OnChange event for radio button in nested form rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working on Ruby on Rails application. Now I want to get **OnChange** event for radio button in my `active-admin` nested form

```
##form code
.......
........
<% f.has_many :scheduler, new_record: false do |s| %>
      <%- s.input :occurance_type, as: :radio, :collection => Scheduler.occurance_types.keys %>
........
```

**Inspected html code** :-

```
<li class="radio input optional" id="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_input">
  <fieldset class="choices">
    <legend class="label">
      <label>Occurance type</label>
    </legend>
    <ol class="choices-group">
      <li class="choice">
        <label for="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_one_time">
          <input id="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_one_time" type="radio" value="One Time" checked="checked" name="property_promotion[scheduler_attributes][occurance_type]">One Time
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="choice">
        <label for="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_recurring">
          <input id="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_recurring" type="radio" value="Recurring" name="property_promotion[scheduler_attributes][occurance_type]">Recurring
        </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</li>
```

I have tried below code but giving syntax error in my browser console :-

```
$('input[type=radio][name=property_promotion[scheduler_attributes][occurance_type]]').change(function() {
    alert("Radio button changed");
});
```

Can anybody suggest me for getting this event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put value of `name` in quotes to indicate that the `[]` are part of the string as in the demo below:

```js
$('input[type=radio][name="property_promotion[scheduler_attributes][occurance_type]"]').change(function() {
    alert("Radio button changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
<li class="radio input optional" id="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_input">
  <fieldset class="choices">
    <legend class="label">
      <label>Occurance type</label>
    </legend>
    <ol class="choices-group">
      <li class="choice">
        <label for="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_one_time">
          <input id="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_one_time" type="radio" value="One Time" checked="checked" name="property_promotion[scheduler_attributes][occurance_type]">One Time
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="choice">
        <label for="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_recurring">
          <input id="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_recurring" type="radio" value="Recurring" name="property_promotion[scheduler_attributes][occurance_type]">Recurring
        </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</li>
</ol>
```

Or you can simplify the selector by using the `radios`' ancestors as in the demo below:

```
'ol.choices-group :radio'
```

```js
$('ol.choices-group :radio').change(function() {
    alert("Radio button changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
<li class="radio input optional" id="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_input">
  <fieldset class="choices">
    <legend class="label">
      <label>Occurance type</label>
    </legend>
    <ol class="choices-group">
      <li class="choice">
        <label for="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_one_time">
          <input id="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_one_time" type="radio" value="One Time" checked="checked" name="property_promotion[scheduler_attributes][occurance_type]">One Time
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="choice">
        <label for="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_recurring">
          <input id="property_promotion_scheduler_attributes_occurance_type_recurring" type="radio" value="Recurring" name="property_promotion[scheduler_attributes][occurance_type]">Recurring
        </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Glad this was helpful.